# Twitter - tweet button API

Tags: twitter

I'm looking into using the Twitter tweet button API, found: [here](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/tweet_button)

I have the following code:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button"
data-url="http://myurl.com/howtouse"
data-counturl="http://myurl.com/howtouse"
data-text="How to use this site"
data-count="vertical"
>Tweet</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

My problem comes with the count. When I hit the 'tweet' button, the popup appears. I post to twitter all fine. The problem then comes with when I then click on the count box, which is 0.

The URL of this is: http://twitter.com/#search?q=http%3A%2F%2Fmyurl.com%2Fhowtouse%2F

Which when clicked returns no results even though I can see the tweet in my timeline.

Does anyone have any ideas why the search wouldn't find the link I shared/tweeted and why the count is 0?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of reasons that Tweets don't show up in search that range from quality filtering to time: http://support.twitter.com/articles/66018-my-tweets-or-hashtags-are-missing-from-search

The tweet count being 0 can be an effect of caching. Generally tweet button counts take a few hours to update for performance reasons and are often inaccurate by a % as well.